# Haskell Convert Time milliseconds to UTCTime

Tags: haskell, time

I have time as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC.
How can I convert it to  UTCTime (Integer -> UTCTime)?
I need UTCTime for inserting it in MongoDB.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried? And where is your code with error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `posixSecondsToUTCTime` in [Data.Time.Clock.POSIX](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.5.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html). As your value is in milliseconds you need to divide it by 1000 first. Here's an example:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Data.Time.Clock.UTC

millisToUTC :: Integer -> UTCTime
millisToUTC t = posixSecondsToUTCTime $ (fromInteger t) / 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to create a UTCTime and add a number of seconds to it:

```
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Clock

-- 1/1/1900 as a Day
jan_1_1900_day = fromGregorian 1900 1 1 :: Day

-- 1/1/1900 as a UTCTime
jan_1_1900_time = UTCTime jan_1_1900_day 0

secs = 86400+3600  -- number of seconds to add to 1/1/1900
                   -- = 1 day + 1 hour

-- add some seconds to 1/1/1900 00:00:00
myTime = addUTCTime (fromIntegral secs) jan_1_1900_time

showTime t = (utctDay t, utctDayTime t) -- to see inside a UTCTime

main = do
  print $ showTime jan_1_1900_time
  print $ showTime myTime
```

The output is:

```
(1900-01-01,0s)
(1900-01-02,3600s)
```

The first argument to `addUTCTime` is a NominalDiffTime which has both a `Num` instance and an `Enum` instance.

Using the `Num` instance, `fromIntegral x` will create a NominalDiffTime of `x` seconds.

Using the `Enum` instance, `toEnum x` will create a NominalDiffTime of `x` picoseconds.

So if you want millisecond resolution on your times, you can use this recipe:

```
millis = (2*86400+3600)*1000  -- milliseconds to add = 2 days + 1 hour

myTime' = addUTCTime (toEnum (millis*10^9)) jan_1_1900_time
```

And then `print $ showtime myTime'` results in:

```
(1900-01-03,3600s)
```